# Derived Result from Butter Filter and FFT doesn't change over time

Tags: python, signals, fft, sensors

I am very new in Signal Processing, have met a situation that I am not sure if it is correct or not.  Please correct me then I will update more details.

My data is [here](https://app.box.com/s/8ijccq76z65itv9jluid3nadfzp160qr)

I acquired an accelerometer signal taken from my cellphone (Samsung Galaxy Note 2, sampling rate $\approx 99 Hz$). I would like to analyze frequency from $0.3 Hz$ to $5.0 Hz$

My procedure is following steps:

1. combination: let say a sensor yields 3 channels $x$, $y$, $z$. The combination is to produce a new channel $v = \sqrt{(x * x + y * y + z * z)}$
2. Perform a median filter: to make signal smoothly
3. Butter-worth filter: my cutoff is from $0.3 Hz$ to $5.0 Hz$
4. FFT

   Below image is my demonstrate with segment of 120 time-points with 4 steps: (can explore more at my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3gsYjdC9dY))
   [image: a segment of 120 time-points]

I observed result of step 3 and 4 do not change while signal varies over time

My question is if there is anything I can make sure this result is correct or not? Thanks in advance

Below is my code was used for applying filters

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
from numpy import absolute
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import medfilt, hilbert
import pandas as pd

chunk = 120
LOW_CUT = 0.3
HIGH_CUT = 5.0
FS = 99
freqs = rfftfreq(chunk, 1 / FS)
_accel = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
for k, g in _accel.groupby(np.arange(len(_accel)) // chunk):
    _v = g['v'].values
    _v = medfilt(_v, 7)
    _v = butter_bandpass_filter(_v, LOW_CUT, HIGH_CUT, FS, order=4)
    v = 1 / chunk * absolute(rfft(_v))
    plt.stem(freqs, v)
```

**update 1** another link to download data https://1drv.ms/u/s!At6qHz_a5mXhgp1KcAYpvsiJeTXsmg

**update 2** updated sampling rate in code `FS = 99`

**update 3** increased chunk size to 512, [plotted](https://youtu.be/CALuLN1vYtc) data again. Made a video of result [without bandpass](https://youtu.be/2jc21kS5VnA)

Comment: Can you post `data.csv` somewhere?

Comment: yes, please check at https://1drv.ms/u/s!At6qHz_a5mXhgp1KcAYpvsiJeTXsmg

Comment: What exactly is `FS`?

Comment: I have updated it, FS = 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the problem a quick try, and below is my snippet

```
data = _accel['v'].tolist()    
Fs = 99
# remove the DC part, to help the plotting later
data = data - np.mean(data)
# Perform FFT for real data, on the whole 6000 samples, 
# using 4096 discrete frequencies, which is dense enough to capture 
# the frequency information within 0.3-5 Hz.    
fdata = rfft(data,4096)

# the frequencies we are looking at in the FFT
freqs = map(lambda x: float(x)*Fs/4096, range(0,4097))

# Plot
plt.plot(freqs[0:2049],fdata)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot does contain information in the band you are interested in.
[Plot of frequency magnitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAZzK.png)

I guess your problem is in choosing chunk too small.
The resolution in the frequency domain is Fs/N, with N is the number of points to perform FFT (and usually the length of the signal vector in the time domain). So, if you want to capture information in the range of 0.3-5Hz, I assume you would need a resolution of about 0.2Hz, which means N should be at least 500. Your choice of 120 for window length is obviously not enough.

Comment: thanks, I increased chunk size to 512 but clearly step 3,4 have same result compared to previous work. https://youtu.be/CALuLN1vYtc

Interestingly, when I removed bandpass, FFT is 0, https://youtu.be/2jc21kS5VnA

Comment: I saw that you filter each chunk separately, which could be the problem. The butterworth filter you used has large delay, and if you do that, each chunk filtered signal will lose a lot of information. You can try to filter the whole signal, then breaking into chunks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time a new chunk of data is processed in your loop, the filtering is initialized with a default state (which correspond to the state of the filter if all previous samples were zeros). As a result, the filter barely has time to settle after the initial transient (caused by the step from those "previous" zeros to the actual data sample values), then does the same thing again for the next chunk of data.

One way to fix this is to filter the entire data set in one shot before processing blocks of data with the FFT:

```
_v = _accel['v'].values
_v = medfilt(_v, 7)
_v = butter_bandpass_filter1(_v, LOW_CUT, HIGH_CUT, FS, order=4)
for k in np.arange(1,len(_accel)//chunk):
     v = _v[chunk*k:chunk*(k+1)]
     v = 1 / chunk * absolute(rfft(v))
     plt.stem(freqs, v)
```

Alternatively you could also keep track of the filter state (`zi` below):

```
def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, zi, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    if (zi == None):
        zi = lfilter_zi(b,a)
    y,zf = lfilter(b, a, data, zi=zi)
    return y,zf

zi = None
for k, g in _accel.groupby(np.arange(len(_accel)) // chunk):
    _v = g['v'].values
    _v = medfilt(_v, 7)
    _v,zi = butter_bandpass_filter(_v, LOW_CUT, HIGH_CUT, FS, zi, order=4)
    v = 1 / chunk * absolute(rfft(_v))
    plt.stem(freqs, v)
```